# How do compilers convert their internal binary representation to decimal for display?

Tags: architecture, binary, type-conversion

By this I don't want a general discussion of methods which convert binary to decimal. I mean specifically, which specific strategy does any specific example system, e.g. a language like Python, Java or C actually use?

Comment: Could you give an example of what sort of "display" you're talking about?  Compilers do not, in normal usage, display their internal representation at all.  And if they did, they're not particularly likely to use decimal to do so.

Comment: What *display* are you talking about? Compilers convert code (text) to a binary representation. They don't convert *binary to decimal for display*, AFAIK.

Comment: OK, what I mean is, how do they go from a binary representation, eg IEEE 754 FP format, to denary. The internal format is IEEE 754 and the display format is decimal. I know the Horner method of doing the conversion, but I don't want to know how to do it, but specifically how They do it. Eg, how does Java do it? How does C++ do it? The maths is done in binary but the display version is decimal. What process to they use to convert?

Answer (score 0):

The `itoa` function is used in C to convert a number (internally represented as binary) to a string of characters.

You can [check the source here](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/lk/+/qcom-dima-8x74-fixes/lib/libc/itoa.c).

To convert a number to its decimal representation, you would pass `10` as the value for the `base` argument.

Other languages would use a similar function.